# How to execute database migrations on startup when using Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant in .NET Core 3.x?

Tags: entity-framework-core, autofac, database-migration, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-3.0

In single-tenanted .NET Core apps, EF Core database migrations (and DB seeding) can be executed immediately after the IHost has been built (typically in Program.cs):

```
await BuildHost(args)
    .MigrateDbContext<I.MyDbContext>()
    .RunAsync();
}
```

since by this point, the one-and-only DB context has been registered.

In multi-tenanted apps, the [tenant-specific registrations are performed much later](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#multitenant-support) - in the  `multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(...)` callback - once the HTTPContext has become available.

The problem is that there seems to be no location after this callback has executed where the tenant-specific context can be retrieved in order to invoke the migration.

I'm sure it's wrong to do it at the end of the `multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(...)` callback since the function of this appears to be purely component registration.

Where should the migration be executed from?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? DbUp? Might be good to add some tags to help the right folks get eyes on this.

Comment: it's EF Core. Good point - edited and swapped a tag (was already using the maximum five!)

Answer (score 1):

You can register a `IStartable` component inside each tenant to start the migration process.

```
public class AutomigrateDatabase : IStartable
{
   public void AutomigrateDatabase(XContext xContext)
   {
       this._xContext = xContext; 
   }

   private readonly XContext _xContext; 

   public void Start()
   {
      this._xContext.Database.Migrate(); 
   }
}
```

and register it like this :

```
mtc.ConfigureTenant('1', b => {
    b.RegisterType<AutomigrateDatabase>().As<IStartable>().SingleInstance();
});
```

You can find more information about startable code in the documentation : [Running code at startup](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html)

Comment: Hi Cyril, Unfortunately this doesn't work since the `Start()` method of `IStartable` gets called as soon as the container is built, but `ConfigureTenant()` doesn't get called until sometime later.

Comment: To clarify: the per-tenant callback set up inside `ConfigureTenant()` doesn't get called until sometime later.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved this using Aufofac's `OnActivated()`.

in `Startup.cs`:

```
public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
{
    // retrieve tenant settings
    CONFIG.Tenancy tenancyConfig = null;
    var tenancyOptions = container.Resolve<IOptions<CONFIG.Tenancy>>();
    if (tenancyOptions != null)
        tenancyConfig = tenancyOptions.Value;

    // create multitenant container
    var accessor = container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var tenantIdentificationStrategy = new HELP.RequestHeaderTenantIdentificationStrategy(accessor, tenancyOptions, container);
    var multitenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentificationStrategy, container);

    // configure tenant-specific dependencies here
    foreach (CONFIG.Tenant tenancy in tenancyConfig.Tenant)
    {
        multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(tenancy.Token, containerBuilder =>
        {
            containerBuilder
                .Register(componentContext =>
                {
                    var serviceProvider = componentContext.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
                    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptions<I.ProjectsContext>(new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>());

                    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<I.ProjectsContext>(dbContextOptions)
                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                        .EnableDetailedErrors()
                        .UseApplicationServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
                        .UseMySql(
                            tenancy.DBConnection.Projects,
                            serverOptions => serverOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                                maxRetryCount: 5,
                                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                errorNumbersToAdd: null));

                    return optionsBuilder.Options;
                })
                .As<DbContextOptions<I.ProjectsContext>>()
                .InstancePerDependency();

            containerBuilder.Register(componentContext => componentContext.Resolve<DbContextOptions<I.ProjectsContext>>())
                .As<DbContextOptions>()
                .InstancePerDependency();

            containerBuilder.RegisterType<I.ProjectsContext>()
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerDependency()
                .OnActivated(sr =>
                    // migrate database after the component is activated
                    sr.Instance.Database.MigrateAsync());
        });
    }

    return multitenantContainer;
}
```